# NullPointerException when I try to connect to a mysql db from javabean

Tags: jdbc, javabeans

NullPointerException when I try to connect to a mysql db from javabean

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page     /ShowProductCatalog.jsp at line 9
<jsp:useBean id= "data" class= "cart.ProductDataBean" scope="request"/>

<html>
    <body>
8:     <body>
9:         <%  List productList = data.getProductList();
10:             Iterator prodListIterator = productList.iterator();
11:           %>
```

root cause

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    cart.ProductDataBean.getProductList(ProductDataBean.java:36)
```

ProductDataBean.java

```
    public ProductDataBean()
    {
        try
        {
                String userName = "root";
                String password = "root";
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:/eshopdb";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                System.out.println("Database connection established");
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }



public ArrayList getProductList() throws SQLException
        {
            ArrayList productList = new ArrayList();
/**********************HERE IS LINE 36. ERROR HERE*******************************/
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();//ERROR HERE
            ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM product");

        Help
```

Answer (score 0):

See if `connection` is null right after assigning to it. (where you print "Database connection established") I suspect it is, and that you really want to be debugging that `DriverManager.getConnection` call. Also, are you sure that `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}` isn't firing?

Comment: I have played around with if statements. And i think that connection is null. how can i fix that

Comment: Although the javadoc for getConnection ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) ) doesn't really say it can ever return null, it sounds like it is doing that when it fails to connect to the DB. What happens if you drop the colon after "localhost" or explicitly make it "localhost:3306" (default port)?

Comment: see also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: can you connect to mysql with other tools, like the command-line `mysql` command?

Comment: yes i can connnect using the mysql workbench. What is wierd is that I am able to create a table in a mysql db from the netbeans IDE and see that that table actually exists by accessing it in the workbench. but when i run my program, it keeps on giving me the null pointer exception